# Js print 1/10 messege using random numbers

Tags: javascript, bash

I got some code here that looks like this:

```
<button onclick="hi()"> try</button>

<script>
function hi()
{
var x=document.getElementById("hello")
x.innerHTML=Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
}
</script>

<script id="hello">
</script>
```

And then i want to add at the end i want to have something that should (in bash) look like this:

```
if %hello%==1 echo <a href='link1'> 1</a>
```

Then at example if the random number is 1 then the website will show link number 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an array of links, then pull out one of those links at random. This code probably won't work, but will give you general idea:

```
var links = ['link1', 'link2', ....];
var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * links.length);
document.writeln('<a href="' + links[rnd] + '">link</a>');
```

Comment: But how to add onclick='hi()' to the
document.writeln('<a href="' + links[rnd] + '">link</a>');